# Bot framework (v4) Prompt choice in carousel using HeroCards not going to next step

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, prompt

I’m trying to use HeroCards along with a prompt choice in a carousel. So the options to be selected by the user are displayed as HeroCards. As soon as the user clicks in the button of a card it should goes to the next waterfall function.

Here is a working example in bot framework v3. It does work as expected.

```
  const cards = (data || []).map(i => {
    return new builder.HeroCard(session)
      .title(`${i.productName} ${i.brandName}`)
      .subtitle(‘product details’)
      .text(‘Choose a product’)
      .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, i.image)])
      .buttons([builder.CardAction.postBack(session, `${i.id.toString()}`, ‘buy’)]);
  });

  const msg = new builder.Message(session);
  msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
  msg.attachments(cards);

  builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, data.map(i => `${i.id.toString()}`), {
    retryPrompt: msg,
  });
```

Below I’m trying to do the same with bot framework v4 but it does not work. It never goes to the next function in my waterfall.

How can I do the same with v4?

…

```
this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL));
```

…

```
const productOptions: Partial<Activity> = MessageFactory.carousel(
  item.map((p: Product) =>
    CardFactory.heroCard(
      p.productName,
      ‘product details’,
      [p.image || ''],
      [
        {
          type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
          title: ‘buy’,
          value: p.id,
        },
      ],
    ),
  ),
  ‘Choose a product’,
);

return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, productOptions);
```

…

**UPDATE:**

Follow full code with the suggestion from @Drew Marsh

```
export class ProductSelectionDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  private selectedProducts: Product[] = [];
  private productResult: Product[][];
  private stateAccessor: StatePropertyAccessor<State>;

  static get Name() {
    return PRODUCT_SELECTION_DIALOG;
  }

  constructor(stateAccessor: StatePropertyAccessor<State>) {
    super(PRODUCT_SELECTION_DIALOG);

    if (!stateAccessor) {
      throw Error('Missing parameter.  stateAccessor is required');
    }

    this.stateAccessor = stateAccessor;

    const choicePrompt = new ChoicePrompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL);
    choicePrompt.style = ListStyle.none;

    this.addDialog(
      new WaterfallDialog<State>(REVIEW_PRODUCT_OPTIONS_LOOP, [
        this.init.bind(this),
        this.selectionStep.bind(this),
        this.loopStep.bind(this),
      ]),
    );

    this.addDialog(choicePrompt);
  }

  private init = async (step: WaterfallStepContext<State>) => {
    const state = await this.stateAccessor.get(step.context);
    if (!this.productResult) this.productResult = state.search.productResult;
    return await step.next();
  };

  private selectionStep = async (step: WaterfallStepContext<State>) => {
    const item = this.productResult.shift();

    const productOptions: Partial<Activity> = MessageFactory.carousel(
      item.map((p: Product) =>
        CardFactory.heroCard(
          p.productName,
          'some text',
          [p.image || ''],
          [
            {
              type: ActionTypes.ImBack,
              title: 'buy',
              value: p.id,
            },
          ],
        ),
      ),
      'Choose a product',
    );

    return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, {
      prompt: productOptions,
      choices: item.map((p: Product) => p.id),
    });
  };

  private loopStep = async (step: WaterfallStepContext<State>) => {
    console.log('step.result: ', step.result);
  };
}
```

**PARENT DIALOG BELOW:**

...

```
this.addDialog(new ProductSelectionDialog(stateAccessor));
```

...

```
if (search.hasIncompletedProducts) await step.beginDialog(ProductSelectionDialog.Name);
```

...

```
return await step.next();
```

...

**MY BOT DIALOG STRUCTURE**

```
onTurn()
>>> await this.dialogContext.beginDialog(MainSearchDialog.Name) (LUIS)
>>>>>> await step.beginDialog(QuoteDialog.Name)
>>>>>>>>> await step.beginDialog(ProductSelectionDialog.Name)
```

**UPDATE**

Replacing the `ChoicePrompt` with `TextPromt` (as suggested by Kyle Delaney) seems to have the same result (do not go to the next step) but I realised that if remove `return` from the prompt like this:

`` return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, `What is your name, human?`); `` TO `` await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, `What is your name, human?`); ``

it does work but when I'm returning the original code with `ChoicePrompt` without `return` like this:

```
await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, {
  prompt: productOptions,
  choices: item.map((p: Product) => p.id),
});
```

I'm getting another error in the framework:

```
error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at values.sort (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/choices/findValues.js:84:48)
    at Array.sort (native)
    at Object.findValues (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/choices/findValues.js:84:25)
    at Object.findChoices (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/choices/findChoices.js:58:25)
    at Object.recognizeChoices (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/choices/recognizeChoices.js:75:33)
    at ChoicePrompt.<anonymous> (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/prompts/choicePrompt.js:62:39)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/prompts/choicePrompt.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/xxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/prompts/choicePrompt.js:3:12)
```

this is the line:

```
    // Sort values in descending order by length so that the longest value is searched over first.
    const list = values.sort((a, b) => b.value.length - a.value.length);
```

I can see the data from my state is coming properly
prompt: <-- the data is ok
choices: <-- the data is ok too

Sometimes I'm getting this error too:

```
error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at ProductSelectionDialog.<anonymous> (/xxxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/componentDialog.js:92:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/xxxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/componentDialog.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

this line

```
            // Check for end of inner dialog
            if (turnResult.status !== dialog_1.DialogTurnStatus.waiting) {
```

Comment: You say it never goes to the next step. Does that mean your bot just keeps sending the same prompt on each turn? Could the problem have to do with your state storage rather than your choice prompt? Please test this by replacing your choice prompt with a simple text prompt and seeing if your waterfall can proceed to the next step.

Comment: just tried like this: return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, 'question ?');

and the problem persist.

Comment: "...same prompt on each turn?" Nope.

Comment: "Could the problem have to do with your state storage rather than your choice prompt?" Not sure. I can access the data from my state normally. So, I don't know.

Comment: just added some logs on my onTurn and it seems to be logging when selecting a choice or simple prompt as this.dialogContext.context.responded as true and status DialogTurnStatus.empty but the dialog was never ended. I hope it can help.

Comment: just to be clear my bot structure so far: onTurn() > this.dialogContext.beginDialog(MainSearchDialog.Name) (LUIS) > step.beginDialog(QuoteDialog.Name) > await step.beginDialog(ProductSelectionDialog.Name);

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to ask you to test with a `TextPrompt` instead of a `ChoicePrompt`. You tested with `PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL` which is the dialog ID for your `ChoicePrompt`. I need you to check if the dialog stack is maintained between turns so we know if it's a problem with state or with your specific dialog. I've observed some channels generating a new conversation ID for each turn, which would be a problem if your dialog stack is in conversation state.

Comment: I just replaced ```ChoicePrompt``` with ```TextPrompt```. It seems to be the same result. I can still see the carousel with cards. On my ```OnTurn``` the ```this.dialogContext.context.responded``` returns ```false``` and my state seems to be up to date with my latest data when I get it with ```await this.stateAccessor.get(this.dialogContext.context)```

Comment: if it helps my bot is using this sample as the base idea: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_typescript/13.basic-bot. Just going deeper in the dialogs.

Comment: I can't believe. I got some progress here. I've changed my prompt to this: await ```return step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, `What is your name, human?`);``` and all as still the same. Then I removed the ```return``` like ```step.prompt(...)``` and now I can get to the next step :| ```step.result:  ventura```. Now getting  another error but might be simpler ```error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined```

Comment: FROM ```return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, `What is your name, human?`);``` TO ```await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, `What is your name, human?`);```

Comment: I'll update my question. It looks like that using the same thing with ChoicePrompt (removing the return) on the original code it creates a new error on bot framework. ```error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``` on this line ```at values.sort (/xxx/xxxxx/Workspace/temp/13.basic-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/choices/findValues.js:84:48)```

Comment: This question is getting a bit too convoluted and comments are not for extended discussion. Please either email me your project or ask a new *very specific* question about one single *very specific* issue you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As I said, the reason I was asking you to test with a text prompt instead of a choice prompt is because it's possible that your dialog state isn't being used correctly. But it's also important for you to have a *very good* understanding of how dialogs work *before* you try to do something highly unusual and experimental like using a carousel as a prompt. Since you mentioned the Basic Bot, it is probably a good idea for you to go back to the basics and get a basic bot working and see if it can go from one dialog step to the next. We don't know if your problem has anything to do with carousels.

Comment: Ok, yes it's getting too broad. I'll close it. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: All right, please mark Drew's answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `ChoicePrompt`, but when you call `prompt` you're only passing through an `activity` (the carousel). `ChoicePrompt` is going to try to validate the input against a set of choices that you should be passing in when you call `prompt`. Because you're not doing this, the prompt is not recognizing the post back value as valid and technically should be reprompting you with the carousel again to make a valid choice.

The fix here should be to call prompt with `PromptOptions` instead of just a raw `Activity` and set the `choices` of the `PromptOptions` to an array that contains all the values you expect back (e.g. the same value you set for the `value` of the post back button).

This should end up looking a little something like this:

Since you're providing the choices UX with your cards, you want to set the `ListStyle` on the `ChoicePrompt` to `none`

```typescript
const productsPrompt = new ChoicePrompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL);
productsPrompt.style = ListStyle.none;

this.addDialog(productsPrompt);
```

Then, set the available `choices` for the specific prompt:

```typescript
return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, {
      prompt: productOptions,
      choices: items.map((p: Product) => p.id),
  });
```

Comment: It does make sense. I'll try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: just updated the question with my try using your suggestion. I'm getting an error as described in the question. When I use my previous approach again I can see the HeroCards in a carousel but not proceed to next waterfall function as you know.

Comment: Just tried using "toString()" for the IDs. choices: item.map((p: Product) => p.id.toString()) and not getting the error anymore but still not expected behaviour. Now it's showing the IDs as options below my HeroCards and even clicking on it does the same behaviour as with HeroCards.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to set ListStyle.none on the ChoicePrompt. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Almost, now the carousel is working and no extra options are displayed under it but  still does not go to the next waterfall function. Is there any documentation out there? I did research a lot about but didn't find anything. Any idea what could be?

Comment: Ah, ok... can you try changing from `ActionTypes.PostBack` to `ImBack` on your buttons? I'm pretty sure that'll do it, but then you'll need to decide if you're ok with that UX. `ChoicePrompt` doesn't handle post backs IIRC.

Comment: Yes, I tried it yesterday as one of my tests. Same result. Might be something else. I'll update the question with full code.

Comment: ActionType is still PostBack in the updated code so, to be clear, you are saying you tried ImBack as well and that didn't work??? I'll see if I can find time to set up this repo to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I tried with ImBack, same result. If you don't see anything wrong in the full code. It could be even before this dialog. The dialog code above is called from another dialog. But I can't see how it should affect the problematic dialog.

Comment: Sorry my stupid question but I'm start wondering if it could be a bug in the framework since I can't find examples doing the same or any documentation. Have you ever seen this working on V4? Should I open a bug on the original repo? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it seems to be related https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/737

Answer (score 0):

Basically Drew Marsh was right.

I just would like to add some other details that I had to tweak to make it work. In case someone else is going crazy like I was. It could give some insights. It's all about how you handle the returns of nested dialogs.

First change. I had to transform the identifier of the Choice prompt into string:

```
        {
          type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
          title: 'buy',
          value: p.id.toString(),
        },
```

and

```
return await step.prompt(PRODUCTS_CAROUSEL, {
  prompt: productOptions,
  choices: item.map((p: Product) => p.id.toString()),
});
```

Another problem that I found was in the parent dialog:

I was basically trying to do this:

```
if (search.hasIncompletedProducts) await step.beginDialog(ProductSelectionDialog.Name);
return await step.next();
```

Which makes no sense, then I changed it to:

```
if (search.hasIncompletedProducts) {
  return await step.beginDialog(ProductSelectionDialog.Name);
} else {
  return await step.next();
}
```

And then the final change in the parent of the parent dialog:

Before was like this:

```
switch (step.result) {
  case ESearchOptions.OPT1:
    await step.beginDialog(OPT1Dialog.Name);
    break;
  default:
    break;
}

await step.endDialog();
```

Which again does not make sense since I should return the beginDialog or endDialog. It was changed to:

```
switch (step.result) {
  case ESearchOptions.OPT1:
    return await step.beginDialog(OPT1Dialog.Name);
  default:
    break;
}
```